# state restoration in iOS

Tags: ios, state-restoration

I am storing my application screen, so that when the application gets opened it will show the screen that was stored. The application is navigation based.

I have assigned the Restoration Ids to my two view controllers in main story board. The first controller is the root view controller of the navigation controller. I have also assigned Restoration Id to the navigation controller. 
Now the problem is when I run the application I am getting the following warning:

> Unable to create restoration in progress marker file.

Not sure what else need to be done.

Comment: I would suggest taking the time to read the Apple documentation on state preservation and restoration. [State Preservation and Resrvation Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cryptic warning without any google results \[In Simulator\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932156/cryptic-warning-without-any-google-results-in-simulator)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same warning before and fixed it by doing the followings.

I was using storyboard. My storyboard only included a navigation view controller and a view controller (which was the root view controller of that navigation view controller). In my case, it was caused by either of the two reasons:

The application was not set up correctly for state preservation
   The followings need to be set:

1. In app delegate, override application:willFinishLaunching. One can simply return YES in that method.
2. For every view controllers and views (including the navigation view controllers and tab view controllers), set a restore ID
3. In app delegate, opt-in by overriding `shouldSaveApplicationState` and `shouldRestoreApplicationState`

If this warning still occurred, you could check how you run your app in Xcode. I ran my app in Xcode simulator and had to follow a specific sequence to trigger state preservation.

- launch the app in Xcode simulator
- In Xcode simulator, click the "**Home**" button to put the app into the background. The `encodeRestorableStateWithCoder` method of the view controller should be called
- go back to Xcode, click the "**stop**" button to terminate the simulation
- In Xcode simulator, double click the "Home" button and then remove the app from the app switcher and
- go back to Xcode, run the app again.

That warning should not appear. When I used other sequences, I saw that warning appearing. When I debugged my app on my device using Xcode, I followed the same sequence and did not see the warning.

I think that warning indicated that because Xcode could not terminate the app correctly, the state restoration file was not correctly saved onto the disk.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that you don't need to do step D above (force-quit the application in the simulator).

Answer (score 1):

Try to give your View a restoration ID. You can do so to open your xib or storyboard and assign the id to your View Controller.

[image]

more details: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2013/05/21/state-preservation-and-restoration.html

Answer (score 0):

## Simulator:

- This happens for the first time on the simulator when the app encodes. (not sure why)
- Subsequent times this warning wouldn't be shown.

## Device:

Try running on the device.

1. Run on device
2. Go to home screen.
3. Stop running on Xcode
4. Remove app from app switcher
5. Run on device again